# creating a envelop in docusign?

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

```
var url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
        var body = "";  

        var options = initializeRequest(url, "GET", body, email, password);

        request(options, function(err, res, body) {
            if(!parseResponseBody(err, res, body)) {
                return;
            }
            baseUrl = JSON.parse(body).loginAccounts[0].baseUrl;
            next(null); 
        });
```

through this piece of code I'm able to login and get complete account detail. email,password and integratorkey all are global. but how could I upload envelope through api?

Answer (score 2):

Envelope Id is the unique identifier that DocuSign assigns to each envelope.  Manually, you can determine the envelope Id of an envlope by doing the following:

- login to the DocuSign web console (using credentials of the user account that sent the Envelope)
- Navigate to the "Sent Items" folder and select the Envelope you're interested in
- With the Envelope selected in the list, click on the word "Envelope" in the lower pane, when you do so you'll see that the Envelope ID is shown: [image: DS screenshot]

Obviously this manual approach isn't sufficient for an application you want to fully automate. Instead of using this manual approach, your integrated application would want to either keep track of envelope Ids as envelopes are created via the application (ex., by storing them in a database), or the application could potentially determine envelope Ids using API calls to search for specific envelopes, or the application could utilize DocuSign Connect to automatically receive notifications about Envelopes, and store the envelope Ids (ex: in a database) for future use.